# Referring to the class name within a type definition in the class body

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

I have problems referencing the class name in typing statements with the class in question. The following code shows the problem:

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, a: C)
        self.a = a

    @property
    def a(self) -> C:
        return self.a
```

The compiler complains that C is undefined. Is what I am trying to do impossible and will I have to abandon the use of typing for this class?

Comment: @Georgy I simply put the name in quotes in the type definition.

Comment: @Georgy, By the way, I am using Python 3.8.3 so some of the material from PEP_0563 is in Python, I did not need to import from `__future__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with this import `from __future__ import annotations` [PEP-0563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/):

```
from __future__ import annotations

class C:
    def __init__(self, a: C):
        self.a = a

    @property
    def a(self) -> C:
        return self.a
```

---

Or simply use a string:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, a: 'C'):
        self.a = a

    @property
    def a(self) -> 'C':
        return self.a
```